# Saving Data That Has Been Passed To A New Activity into A SQLite Database

Tags: javascript, android, android-sqlite, primary-key

I have been struggling with this for several days now.  When I create a new league and open the BowlerActivity I can see the value of the Primary Key being passed to it.  For example, if Dummy League = 5, I can see this value in the next activity.  My issue is that I want to be able to associate this value (5) to a bowler when they are created.  I cannot seem to get the passed value into the Dialog for creating a new bowler; In order to save it to the bowler table in my database.

Passing the Primary Key from the MainActivity using

```
//On Long Click On The RecyclerView Item An Alert Dialog Is Opened With The Option To Choose Edit/Delete
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this,
                recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, final int position) {

                int leagueId = leaguesList.get(position).getId();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BowlerActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("leagueId", leagueId);
                startActivity(myIntent);
             }
```

BowlerActivity

```
public class BowlerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BowlerAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<Bowler> bowlersList = new ArrayList<>();
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TextView noBowlersView;

    private TextView bowlerLeagueId;

    private DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bowler);
        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        String savedExtra = String.valueOf(getIntent().getIntExtra("leagueId",1));
        TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLeagueId);
        final String s = myText.toString();
        myText.setText(savedExtra);

        coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        noBowlersView = findViewById(R.id.empty_bowlers_view);


        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        bowlersList.addAll(db.getAllBowlers());

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_bowler_fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showBowlerDialog(false, null, -1);
            }
        });

        mAdapter = new BowlerAdapter(this, bowlersList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, 16));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        toggleEmptyBowlers();



        //On Long Click On The RecyclerView Item An Alert Dialog Is Opened With The Option To Choose Edit/Delete
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this,
                recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, final int position) {

                //Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SeriesActivity.class);
                //startActivity(myIntent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                showActionsDialog(position);
            }
        }));
    }

    //Inserting New Bowler In The Database And Refreshing The List
    private void createBowler(String bowler) {
        //Inserting Bowler In The Database And Getting Newly Inserted Bowler Id
        long id = db.insertBowler(bowler);

        //Get The Newly Inserted Bowler From The Database
        Bowler n = db.getBowler(id);

        if (n != null) {
            //Adding New Bowler To The Array List At Position 0
            bowlersList.add(0, n);

            //Refreshing The List
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            toggleEmptyBowlers();
        }
    }

    //Updating Bowler In The Database And Updating The Item In The List By Its Position
    private void updateBowler(String name, int position) {
        Bowler n = bowlersList.get(position);

        //Updating Bowler Text
        n.setName(name);
        //n.setLeagueId(  );

        //Updating The Bowler In The Database
        db.updateBowler(n);

        //Refreshing The List
        bowlersList.set(position, n);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

        toggleEmptyBowlers();
    }

    //Deleting Bowler From SQLite Database And Removing The Bowler Item From The List By Its Position
    private void deleteBowler(int position) {
        // deleting the note from db
        db.deleteBowler(bowlersList.get(position));

        //Removing The Bowler From The List
        bowlersList.remove(position);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

        toggleEmptyBowlers();
    }

    //Opens Dialog With Edit/Delete Options
    //Edit - 0
    //Delete - 0
    private void showActionsDialog(final int position) {
        CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[]{"Edit", "Delete"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose option");
        builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {
                    showBowlerDialog(true, bowlersList.get(position), position);
                } else {
                    deleteBowler(position);
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    //Show Alert Dialog With EditText Options to Enter/Edit A League
    //When shouldUpdate = true, It Will Automatically Display Old Bowler Name And Change The Button Text To UPDATE
    private void showBowlerDialog(final boolean shouldUpdate, final Bowler bowler, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        View view = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.dialog_bowler, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderUserInput = new AlertDialog.Builder(BowlerActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilderUserInput.setView(view);



        final EditText inputBowler = view.findViewById(R.id.etBowlerNameInput);
        //final EditText inputBowlerLeagueId = view.findViewById( R.id.tvLeagueId );
        TextView dialogTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
        dialogTitle.setText(!shouldUpdate ? getString(R.string.lbl_new_bowler_title) : getString(R.string.lbl_edit_bowler_title));

        if (shouldUpdate && bowler != null) {
            inputBowler.setText(bowler.getName());

        }
        alertDialogBuilderUserInput
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(shouldUpdate ? "update" : "save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {
                                dialogBox.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilderUserInput.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Show Toast Message When No Text Is Entered
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inputBowler.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(BowlerActivity.this, "Enter Bowler!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                } else {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }


                //Check If User Is Updating Bowler
                if (shouldUpdate && bowler != null) {

                    //Updating Bowler By Its Id
                    updateBowler(inputBowler.getText().toString(), position);
                } else {
                    //Creating New Bowler
                    createBowler(inputBowler.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //Toggling List And Empty Bowler View
    private void toggleEmptyBowlers() {
        //You Can Check bowlerList.size() > 0

        if (db.getBowlersCount() > 0) {
            noBowlersView.setVisibility( View.GONE);
        } else {
            noBowlersView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Any assistance with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you get when you log the `savedExtra` value? Note: try to use `MainActivity.this` instead of `getBaseContext` when setting up `Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BowlerActivity.class);`

Comment: The saveExtra is showing the correct Primary Key from the election in the previous activity. My issue is getting this value from saveExtra to be accessible to the add bowler dialog in order to write the League primary key to the bowler table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to give the **savedExtra** variable greater scope and then use that. So :-

1. declare **savedExtra** as a class variable.
2. change where it is decalred and set to only set the value, not declare it.
3. set the new bowler's id using the **savedExtra** variable.

The following code (see comments with //<<<< ?????? for the changed added code) is what I believe would resolve the issue:-

```
public class BowlerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BowlerAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<Bowler> bowlersList = new ArrayList<>();
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TextView noBowlersView;

    private TextView bowlerLeagueId;

    private DatabaseHelper db;
    private String savedExtra; //<<<< Added change 1.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bowler);
        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        savedExtra = String.valueOf(getIntent().getIntExtra("leagueId",1)); //<<<< Saved Extra change 2.
        TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLeagueId);
        final String s = myText.toString();
        myText.setText(savedExtra);

        coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        noBowlersView = findViewById(R.id.empty_bowlers_view);


        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        bowlersList.addAll(db.getAllBowlers());

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_bowler_fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showBowlerDialog(false, null, -1);
            }
        });

        mAdapter = new BowlerAdapter(this, bowlersList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, 16));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        toggleEmptyBowlers();



        //On Long Click On The RecyclerView Item An Alert Dialog Is Opened With The Option To Choose Edit/Delete
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this,
                recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, final int position) {

                //Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SeriesActivity.class);
                //startActivity(myIntent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                showActionsDialog(position);
            }
        }));
    }

    //Inserting New Bowler In The Database And Refreshing The List
    private void createBowler(String bowler) {
        //Inserting Bowler In The Database And Getting Newly Inserted Bowler Id
        bowler.setLeagueId(savedExtra); //<<<< ADDED change 3.
        long id = db.insertBowler(bowler);

        //Get The Newly Inserted Bowler From The Database
        Bowler n = db.getBowler(id);

        if (n != null) {
            //Adding New Bowler To The Array List At Position 0
            bowlersList.add(0, n);

            //Refreshing The List
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            toggleEmptyBowlers();
        }
    }

    //Updating Bowler In The Database And Updating The Item In The List By Its Position
    private void updateBowler(String name, int position) {
        Bowler n = bowlersList.get(position);

        //Updating Bowler Text
        n.setName(name);
        //n.setLeagueId(  );

        //Updating The Bowler In The Database
        db.updateBowler(n);

        //Refreshing The List
        bowlersList.set(position, n);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

        toggleEmptyBowlers();
    }

    //Deleting Bowler From SQLite Database And Removing The Bowler Item From The List By Its Position
    private void deleteBowler(int position) {
        // deleting the note from db
        db.deleteBowler(bowlersList.get(position));

        //Removing The Bowler From The List
        bowlersList.remove(position);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

        toggleEmptyBowlers();
    }

    //Opens Dialog With Edit/Delete Options
    //Edit - 0
    //Delete - 0
    private void showActionsDialog(final int position) {
        CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[]{"Edit", "Delete"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose option");
        builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {
                    showBowlerDialog(true, bowlersList.get(position), position);
                } else {
                    deleteBowler(position);
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    //Show Alert Dialog With EditText Options to Enter/Edit A League
    //When shouldUpdate = true, It Will Automatically Display Old Bowler Name And Change The Button Text To UPDATE
    private void showBowlerDialog(final boolean shouldUpdate, final Bowler bowler, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        View view = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.dialog_bowler, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderUserInput = new AlertDialog.Builder(BowlerActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilderUserInput.setView(view);



        final EditText inputBowler = view.findViewById(R.id.etBowlerNameInput);
        //final EditText inputBowlerLeagueId = view.findViewById( R.id.tvLeagueId );
        TextView dialogTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
        dialogTitle.setText(!shouldUpdate ? getString(R.string.lbl_new_bowler_title) : getString(R.string.lbl_edit_bowler_title));

        if (shouldUpdate && bowler != null) {
            inputBowler.setText(bowler.getName());

        }
        alertDialogBuilderUserInput
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(shouldUpdate ? "update" : "save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {
                                dialogBox.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilderUserInput.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Show Toast Message When No Text Is Entered
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inputBowler.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(BowlerActivity.this, "Enter Bowler!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                } else {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }


                //Check If User Is Updating Bowler
                if (shouldUpdate && bowler != null) {

                    //Updating Bowler By Its Id
                    updateBowler(inputBowler.getText().toString(), position);
                } else {
                    //Creating New Bowler
                    createBowler(inputBowler.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //Toggling List And Empty Bowler View
    private void toggleEmptyBowlers() {
        //You Can Check bowlerList.size() > 0

        if (db.getBowlersCount() > 0) {
            noBowlersView.setVisibility( View.GONE);
        } else {
            noBowlersView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** this is in-principle code and has not been tested so may contain errors.

Comment: Oops my mistake change 1 altered accordingly (reapply the changes). I didn't change the default value from 1 to 2 in `getIntExtra("leagueId",1)`. However, as before I'd suggest using 0 or -1. This is the value of the int returned if the extra cannot be obtained. e.g. If `getIntExtra("not_an_extra_key",-666)` were used (assuming no extra with a key of ***not_an_extra_key*** existed) then the returned int would be ***-666***. So if you use -1 as a default it could be used to indicate that for some reason the extra didn't exist.

Comment: The three changes you indicated above only insert the Primary Key into the Bowler LeagueId column after you create the bowler and then update them.  I attempted to use the same principle that you did on the update with the create bowler and I was successful with getting the League Id inserted for both the creation and update of a bowler.  One question though in change 2 you changed 1 to a 2, what exactly does this do, broaden the scope of the variable?

Comment: Forget my last question, you explained in the comment above.  Once again thanks a lot for you help MikeT

Comment: If you also check the answer I moved 3 up (sorry should have said, instead just said reapply the changes assuming you'd change 3 as well). Great that it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make your dialog a [`DialogFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment) and pass the value in its argument bundle. A `DialogFragment` has a few advantages over a "bare" `AlertDialog`, including being recreated automatically on a configuration change. I find it easiest to override the fragment's `onCreateDialog` to return an `AlertDialog`. You can retrieve the arguments bundle in that method and use it in the click listeners on the dialog buttons.